# Mechanism for the ring contraction

Tags: organic-chemistry

In this reaction I am unable to understand its mechanism. How the peroxide HCCL3 is causing the ring contraction. I know that the 8 member ring is unstable due to strain and hence it will try to contract. But I am not able to initiate the mechanism due to reagents present. Please can someone explain me how the contraction of 8 members ring to 2 five member ring is taking place?

[image]

Comment: Peroxide is acting as a source of radicals.

Comment: @Waylander what will be the first step?

Comment: Creation of the CCl3 radical and addition to one of the double bonds. See this for a summary  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Smith)/Chapter_15%3A_Radical_Reactions/15.13%3A_Radical_Addition_Reactions_to_Double_Bonds

Comment: @Zenix: This is a radical reaction. Peroxide initiate the radical formation by abstracting a hydrogen from $\ce{HCCl3}$ to form $\ce{^.CCl3}$ radical, which attacks one of the double bond first, and rearrangement happens there after to give $2^\circ$ carbon radical. It abstract hydrogen from another $\ce{HCCl3}$ to give the product and another $\ce{^.CCl3}$ radical, so reaction progress to the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has already been said in the comments, this is a free radical-based reaction. The peroxide $\ce{R1-O-O-R2}$ acts as a radical initiator( where $\ce{R1}$ and $\ce{R2}$ represent alkyl groups). These peroxide radicals generate $\ce{^.CCl3}$ which attacks the double bond and completes the reaction as shown.

An important point to note is that $\ce{^.CCl3}$ is regenerated at the end of the reaction, so it can be described as a catalytic intermediate for this mechanism

[image]